# Create a column with values created from all other columns as a JSON in PySPARK

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe as below:

```
+----------+----------+--------+
|     FNAME|     LNAME|     AGE| 
+----------+----------+--------+
|      EARL|     JONES|      35|
|      MARK|      WOOD|      20|
+----------+----------+--------+
```

I am trying to add a new column as value to this dataframe which should be like this:

```
+----------+----------+--------+------+------------------------------------+
|     FNAME|     LNAME|     AGE|                            VALUE          |
+----------+----------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
|      EARL|     JONES|      35|{"FNAME":"EARL","LNAME":"JONES","AGE":"35"}|
|      MARK|      WOOD|      20|{"FNAME":"MARK","WOOD":"JONES","AGE":"20"} |
+----------+----------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
```

I am not able to achieve this using withColumn or any json function.

Any headstart would be appreciated.

```
Spark: 2.3
Python: 3.7.x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using the SQL function `to_json`which you can find in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`

Here's the solution :

`df.withColumn("VALUE", to_json(struct($"FNAME", $"LNAME", $"AGE"))`

And you can also avoid specifying the columns' names as follows :

`df.withColumn("VALUE", to_json(struct(df.columns.map(col): _*)`

PS: the code I provided is written in scala, but it's the same logic for Python, you just have to use a spark SQL function which is available in both programming languages.

I hope It helps,

Comment: Trying to convert the select * in python

Comment: Achieved using df.withColumn("Value", to_json(struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])))

Comment: This seems to be working..But say if we have another nested object like Address(struct type) how can the above line of code to_json(struct(df.columns.map(col): _* be modified?

Answer (score 1):

**scala** solution:

```
  val df2 = df.select(
    to_json(
      map_from_arrays(lit(df.columns), array('*))
    ).as("value")
  )
```

**pyton** solution: (I don't know how to do it for n-cols like in scala because `map_from_arrays` not exists in pyspark)

```
    import pyspark.sql.functions as f

    df.select(f.to_json(
        f.create_map(f.lit("FNAME"), df.FNAME, f.lit("LNAME"), df.LNAME, f.lit("AGE"), df.AGE)
        ).alias("value")
    ).show(truncate=False)
```

**output**:

```
    +-------------------------------------------+
    |value                                      |
    +-------------------------------------------+
    |{"FNAME":"EARL","LNAME":"JONES","AGE":"35"}|
    |{"FNAME":"MARK","LNAME":"WOOD","AGE":"20"} |
    +-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The Python solution helps but in reality I might have atleast 150 columns per dataframe and a select * should come in handy.

Comment: I've tried to do  it this way but am receiving errors maybe it will help you. List of lists (col_name, column) is flattened in `l2` and passed to `create_map`.
`l1 = [[i,df(i)] for i in list] l2 = [i for s in l1 for i in s] df.select(to_json(create_map(*l2))).show()`

Comment: This will do:- df.withColumn("Value", to_json(struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])))

Answer (score 0):

Achieved using:

```
df.withColumn("VALUE", to_json(struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])))
```